# How to remove rows with specific missing tags from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, data-manipulation

In a Pandas dataframe, '-999' (as integer) is used as a tag to indicate the 'cells' with missing data. I am cleaning up the data by removing rows if a row contains '-999' in it. I tried this method:

```
flag = (dataframe != -999)
dataframe = dataframe[flag]
```

However, the resulting dataframe still has the same shape and the cells with -999 now became empty. Then I used another line:

```
dataframe.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all', inplace = True)
```

But it did not remove those rows as I expected. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.any(axis=1)` or `.all(axis=1)` for that:

```
In [92]: df
Out[92]:
     a    b    c
0    8    7    6
1    8    0 -999
2    8    9    9
3 -999    8    9
4    4    7    6
5    5    9    9
6    6    4    8
7    5 -999    9
8    5    0    5
9    0    6    5

In [93]: df.loc[~(df == -999).any(axis=1)]
Out[93]:
   a  b  c
0  8  7  6
2  8  9  9
4  4  7  6
5  5  9  9
6  6  4  8
8  5  0  5
9  0  6  5
```

or, alternatively, using `.all(axis=1)`:

```
In [94]: df.loc[(df != -999).all(axis=1)]
Out[94]:
   a  b  c
0  8  7  6
2  8  9  9
4  4  7  6
5  5  9  9
6  6  4  8
8  5  0  5
9  0  6  5
```